# Does truecrypt leave behind temporary files

Tags: nautilus, truecrypt, images, privacy

I've I have some scans of sensitive documents in image format such as jpg png etc.  When I open up the folder containing them which is in a truecrypt file, will nautilus create a temporary version of the scan or even a thumbnail of the scan on the computer which the file was opened on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TrueCrypt won't, but I don't know about Nautilus. If you want to make sure, check all the files that have been modified during your session:

```
find /tmp /var/tmp ~/ -type f -mmin 42
```

where 42 is the number of minutes you've been logged in (the `last` command might help if you didn't check the time). You can search for image specifically:

```
find /tmp /var/tmp ~/ -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -mmin 42
```

Of course, if you don't trust the administrators of the computer, you'll never know if they secretly keep a copy of every file that's been on the machine ever.

Comment: Don't forget to clean out ~/.thumbnails (or possibly ~/.gnome-thumbnails).

Comment: Ah, ~/.thumbnails has thumbnails of my sensitive scans...  Will those locations be the only locations where thumbnails are created?

Comment: Looks like thumbnails do get created.  How do I delete them securely so they cannot be undeleted?

Comment: @oshirowanen Replace `~/.thumbnails` by a symbolic link to a directory inside your TrueCrypt volume.

Comment: @Gilles, not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: @oshirowanen: `mv ~/.thumbnails ~/.local.thumbnails && mkdir /path/to/truecrypt/volume/thumbnails && ln -s /path/to/truecrypt/volume/thumbnails ~/.thumbnails`